# Why an energy constraint gives the canonical ensemble (NVT) when we maximize von Neumann entropy, when energy is not conserved in NVT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, density-operator

In Sakurai and Napolitano's *Modern Quantum Mechanics 2nd Edition*, I'm learning *Section 3.4, page 188* where they derive the canonical ensemble by maximizing von Neumann entropy with energy constraint. Basically, in (3.4.46), $$\sum_{k} \delta \rho_{k k}\left[\left(\ln \rho_{k k}+1\right)+\beta E_{k}+\gamma\right]=0,$$ because of the additional $\beta E_k$, we have (3.4.48) which is the canonical ensemble, $$\rho_{k k}=\frac{\exp \left(-\beta E_{k}\right)}{\sum_{l}^{N} \exp \left(-\beta E_{l}\right)}.$$

I do not understand, because as I studied in Statistical Physics, isn't the canonical ensemble, *NVT*, where energy is **not** conserved? Meanwhile, we arrived at a microcanonical-like ensemble in (3.4.49), $\rho_{kk}=\frac{1}{N}$, by **removing** the energy constraint. Shouldn't it be the other way around, that energy constraint leads to *NVE*, and no constraint *NVT*?

A possible explanation I try to think of is that because the system is at thermal equilibrium, therefore energy is unchanged. However, doesn't that mean the canonical ensemble at infinite time is *NVTE* and also is microcanonical? Since $\rho_{kk}$ is now simultaneously diagonalized with $H$, that'd mean $N$ is the number of energy states, and we'd have

$$\rho_{k k}=\frac{\exp \left(-\beta E_{k}\right)}{\sum_{l}^{N} \exp \left(-\beta E_{l}\right)} = \frac{1}{N} \ \forall k \Rightarrow E_k = E_l \ \forall k,l,$$

which makes absolutely no sense. Can anyone point out where my thinking is wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You don't maximize the entropy under the constraint of constant energy, but under the constraint of a fixed energy expectation value... cf. equation 3.4.44

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the difference between the total energy and average energy $U = Tr (\rho H)$ of an ensemble $\rho$? The way I understand it they are the same, because we're only measuring the ensemble, and every time we measure it we get some energy value, and measuring many times and averaging out gives $U$.

Comment: I don't understand. Just compare the two maximizations; both are with respect to different constraints. One with fixed average energy $U=\mathrm{Tr}\rho H$ and one with fixed energy $E$. In the latter case, the probability to measure a different energy $E^\prime \neq E$ is (or must be) zero, while in the former case the probability to measure $E$ is $\propto e^{-\beta E}$, where $\beta$ is related to $U$.

Comment: I see. So does that mean in the microcanonical ensemble, all microstates have the same energy?